# How to change/add JVM custom/system properties & make them reflect without application server restart

Tags: java, jvm, application-server, jvm-arguments

I've a dynamic web application that reads JVM properties continuously. But when i made any change to jcm custom/system properties through application server console (ex. WebSphere) they were not getting reflected immediately. It requires a restart. is there any script or crooked way to update JVM system properties without restarting application server

Comment: That depends on the properties you want to change.  Some are reflected immediately, so I assume you are trying to change something which is not easily reflected dynamically.

Comment: I'm trying to change/add JVM System properties not application server related properties which inevitably requires restart.

Comment: Some system properties are informational only. i.e. they tell you what the value was set to, some defaults can be changed, provided al the code which used it is updated.  Which properties specifically are you trying to change.

Comment: Actually, i inserted few custom properties of my application in to jvm system properties. i want to control the application through updating the jvm system properties.

Comment: You can change the System properties to anything you want at any time.  If there is components which depend on these properties, you need to notify them of the change.

Comment: thank you Peter, but when i change any jvm system property through application server admin console, i need to restart the server to reflect the change. is there any way to inject a jvm system property out side the application code & which wont involve any server restarts

Comment: When you are not using an application server, it happen immediately so I am not sure why this is needed. :|